# Implement fetch in alexa Lamda Intent handler

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am attempting to use the native fetch command in Node JS in a intent handler. I am getting a syntax error on the await clause. What do I need to do to implement this clean http call?

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
        await fetch('https://api.weather.gov/points/38.8894,-77.0352')
        .then(res => res.json());
```

the code executes without await but the response does not wait for fetch to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you declared your handler as an async function ?  You must do this when the function contains an await clause.
Secodly, I'd ditch the .then processing, it's cleaner to do the following:

```
// Handler declared as async, required for functions with an await

async handle(handlerInput) {
        
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const res = await fetch('https://api.weather.gov/points/38.8894,-77.0352');
const obj = await res.json();

// Do with obj whatever you want.
 

}
```